# Declare Constants in Rdl reports Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, plsql

I created and RDL report and I am trying to build a Query Expression.

I am getting error for constant Declaration.

My Query Expression :

```
SELECT *
  FROM master
 WHERE error_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:MDT_FRMDATE, "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS")
                      AND TO_DATE(:MDT_TODATE, "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS")
   AND progress_status = "ERROR"
   AND m.mdt_no = :MDT_No;
```

Error :

> One or more errors occurred during processing of command. ORA-00904:
>   "ERROR": invalid identifier

Comment: That would appear to be an Oracle PL/SQL error (an error in your select query), not a Reporting Services issue. I've added tags so that Oracle programmers might be able to help you.

Comment: I executed query successfully in Toad, but the same query is not working in rdl Query Expression..

Answer (score 0):

I think whatever Oracle driver is being used by Reporting Services is interpreting the double quotes around ERROR as making it an object identifer rather than a string.

Try changing that part of the code to use single quotes:

```
and progress_status = 'ERROR'
```

Comment: I tried to use Single Quotations earlier, but it's considering as a comment and showing in green color..and it's not executing the query after single quote...

Comment: I'm not an Oracle expert but I'm pretty sure single quote does not indicate a comment in Oracle SQL, so there must be some other issue.